# Google Apps Script Error: Service using too much computer time for one day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I wrote a small script that grabs a range of four cells from one sheet and copies that range to the last row (about 1K rows down) of a different sheet in the same file. This script copies and pastes three times in total, it's not complicated. There is a daily trigger attached, and I'm getting regular, but not constant, failures showing the "too much computer time exception."

How do I tell which quota my script is exceeding? I know there is the 6 hour per day quota, but assuming the day resets around midnight in my time zone, I've only used about one hour by the time this trigger fires. Also, if it is due to the 6 hours/day limit, why do other scripts that I have triggering around the same time and very soon after this trigger execute without any problems? If I have exceeded the quota, shouldn't all other scripts be disabled until the quota resets?

The script runs manually in 5 secs, so it shouldn't be hitting the 30 min max either. What can I do to troubleshoot?

**Update** added actual script below:

```
function copyrevtotal() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var adw = ss.getSheetByName("adw");
var revenue = ss.getSheetByName("revenue");
var bing = ss.getSheetByName("bing");
var yahoo = ss.getSheetByName("yahoo");

revenue.getRange("B8:E8").copyTo(adw.getRange(adw.getLastRow()+0,6), 
{contentsOnly:true});
revenue.getRange("B3:E3").copyTo(bing.getRange(bing.getLastRow()+0,6),   
{contentsOnly:true});
revenue.getRange("B15:E15").copyTo(yahoo.getRange(yahoo.getLastRow()+0,6), 
{contentsOnly:true});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [exception message](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages) should be telling you which [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas) or [limitation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) you reached. That exception is not limited to only reaching the quota. It may also be possible that you are reaching a certain [limit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations). You can check the table that lists the hard limitations. For example:

> **Script runtime:**
>
> - **Consumer (e.g., gmail.com)**: 6 min / execution
> - **G Suite Business / Enterprise / EDU**: 30 min / execution
>
> **Custom function runtime:**
>
> - **Consumer (e.g., gmail.com)**: 30 sec / execution
> - **G Suite Business / Enterprise / EDU**: 30 sec / execution

Comment: The documentation isn't clear here, which is why I don't know what the problem is. 
The exception is "Service using too much computer time for one day." The documentation points me to "triggers total runtime", which says 6 hours per day. However, I'm pretty sure I haven't used 6 hrs when this script runs (early morning) and there are other scripts running at the same time that don't fail, which makes me wonder how only one script could exceed a daily quota.

Comment: Time is not the only factor for exception. The [current limitations guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) states that the usage of triggers per script per user is limited to 20 (20 triggers/user/script). Perhaps this script which throws the exception has more than that?

Comment: @jaque I added the actual script to the original post. It has only one trigger, time based to run once every day.